# make: install: Command not found

Tags: git, makefile, qnx, qnx-neutrino

While I'm trying to install `git` from its source on `qnx`, I get the following error (note that pound is a prompt for sudo in `qnx`):

```
# ./configure --without-iconv --with-perl=/usr/pkg/bin/perl --with-python=/usr/qnx650/host/qnx6/x86/usr/bin/python
# make all
# make install
    GEN perl/PM.stamp
    SUBDIR gitweb
    SUBDIR ../
make[2]: `GIT-VERSION-FILE' is up to date.
    GEN git-instaweb
    SUBDIR git-gui
    SUBDIR gitk-git
    SUBDIR perl
    SUBDIR git_remote_helpers
    SUBDIR templates
install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/bin'
make: install: Command not found
make: *** [install] Error 127
```

I've seen many `make: %XXX%: Command not found` issues upon Googling where `%XXX%` is arbitrary executable, but haven't seen it replaced with `install`. What is wrong?

I posted some files of possible interest from `git`'s home directory: [Makefile](http://pastebin.com/ZLJk1kF2), [config.status](http://pastebin.com/P7nbewdL)

`QNX` 6.5.0 SDP SP1, `git` 1.8.3.2

Comment: `install` is a utility that is a part of `GNU coreutils`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with the makefile.
Check if you have `install` utility

```
$~ install --help
```

If you dont have then you can get it from `GNU coreutils`. If you have `install` somewhere then export its path in `PATH` variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/install-utility
```