# Unable to install json 1.8.3 in ruby 2.2.1

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems, bundler

I am running `bundle install` in `Ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]` (installed with rvm 1.25.33) and `bundler 1.10.6`

When it tries to install json 1.8.3, I get the following:

```
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150905-31357-cgs3dn.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so

make "DESTDIR=" install
./install -m 0755 generator.so ./.gem.20150905-31357-199esvy/json/ext
make: ./install: Command not found
make: *** [install-so] Error 127

make install failed, exit code 2
```

On the same host, I am able to install json 1.8.3 in ruby 2.1.3.

In [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444777/make-install-command-not-found) I see the suggestion to make sure that `install` is available. I get valid output when I do `install --help`.

What should I do? Why is the gem able to install in 2.1.3 and not 2.2.1?

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, so I'll add it as a comment: the host in question is a DigitalOcean VPS

Answer (score 13):

simple fix delete your gem.lock file and run bundle install this should rebuild the gemlock file and fix the issue, i was getting the same error when trying to move my development environment from nitrous.io to cloud9,. hope this help

copy from migs120's answer https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253

I use macOS sierra, it's work fine.

Comment: Thank you! I found the answers helpful. I ended up simply doing "bundle update json"

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest try this for MacOS,

```
bundle update json --conservative
```

It will resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Install the following package in ubuntu

sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev

For more information
https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253

Answer (score 1):

In OSX, do the following

```
brew install coreutils
```